How to Submit a recordEditForm from the success of another
I'm having trouble submitting one recordEditForm from the success callback of another. I'm doing this because the user needs to think the two forms/objects are actually one.
Here's what I have...I have two recordEditForms. My first form submits and succeeds.
[Form 1]

[Form 2]

[Form 1 Success]

From the success of form 1 I'm attempting to call component.find('caEditForm').submit(fields); for the second recordEditForm but I'm unable to get the correct fields. The fields in the event.getParams("fields") are from form 1.
I haven't been able to find a way to get the list of fields for form 2.
I've tried using an onchange on form 2 to construct a fields list manually. I can easily get the value from that but it doesn't include the field name. A suggested solution was to use event.getSource().get("v.fieldName") but that throws an error [Salesforce aura TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter]
